# Add line break to js table header label

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table with such header :

```
 <th key={col.label}
     style={col.size}
     class={col.class}
     scope="col"
     height="20">
```

I take labels from columns(col is an item of cycle). Columns is an array with such elements

```
this.columns.push({
   label: this.labels.lbl_forecastYTD + ' - ' + this.labels.lbl_opportunity ,
   fieldName: 'GainSum__c', 
   type: 'number',
   size: "width: 21%;", 
   class: BASE_HEADER_CLASS,
   borderRightSize: "width:  21%;"
});
```

I really want to add a line break to labels, but '\n' doesn't seem to be worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `th { white-space: pre; }` and `\n` will work.